# What type of lens do I need to build a ciné film scanner

Tags: lens

I want to build a scanner to digitise standard 8mm ciné film using my Eumig 8mm projector and a Raspberry Pi with the [High Quality camera module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera/). I am not too worried about the mechanical, electronics and programming side of things, but I am not sure what type of lens to use.

I have a 50mm, f/2, C-mount lens from my Zorki-4K 35mm camera, and I intend to try that before looking for a specific lens for the camera module (which has a C-mount and a CS adapter).

A standard 8mm frame has a diagonal of 5.6mm, and the  RPi HQ camera's sensor has a diagonal of 7.9mm, so 1:1 magnification would be ideal. Will my 50mm lens be suitable, and how do I calculate the object distance and sensor distance from the lens (and from what point on the lens axis)? If my 50mm is not suitable, what type of lens should I look for?

I will, of course, be replacing the projector's incandescent lamp with a white LED for the purposes of scanning.

Hopefully, I have included enough information.

Comment: Most film transfer setups project onto a ground glass screen, and photograph that from the other side. Were you planning to use the projector's lens at all, or take it off? I did some 8mm transfers, and I found that with some adjustments, I could get my 8mm projector to project a focused image directly onto the sensor of a full-frame camera (no lens on the camera). This makes a better image than ground glass. I also used an LED. No matter what lens(es) you use,  you must be concerned about synchronization and flicker.